# Not showing font Awesome version5 icon with vis.js. Shows only a square box

Tags: vis.js, font-awesome-5

I am using vis.js with font awesome version 5.9. 
It is showing an empty square initially. But when i click on that empty square it turns the actual icon. It didn't show when i add the icon.
After that when i click on another icon i.e. start. it turns back to square.
All the required files are present in the source i.e. fontawesome.css changed to all.css in version 5, vis network js and css.

Tried all of the solution that are available on documentation and are present on stackoverflow.

```
 shape: 'icon',
 icon: {
      face: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
      code: '\uf46d',
      size: 50,
      color: 'red'
    },
```

Comment: I solved this problem by adding image of the font-awesome icons

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this?

I tried replacing Font Awesome 4 in examples by Font Awesome 5 and got the same issue. It seems like FA5 changed something and it's no longer compatible with Vis Network. We should probably open an issue: https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/new.

Comment: Font Awesome 4 is working perfectly with the vis js network

Comment: Yeah, 4 does but 5 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It works with Font Awesome Pro and double quoting (still required even with Vis.Js 6.12):

```
    "icon": {
        "face" : "'Font Awesome 5 Pro'",
        "code" : "\uf0c0",
        "size" : 50,
        "color" : "green"
    }
```

because Font Awesome Pro defines bold font as "Solid" and not bold as "Regular".

In Font Awesome Free there is only bold font defined. One work around not tested would be to add not bold font to Font Awesome, or modify VisJS to use only bold fonts even if icon is not selected.